# Move Floor plans side by side in FME

Tags: fme-form

I have multistory building plans and each floor located the same place.

I need to move each floors side by side.

for example, 15 floors need to move side to side as like 5 (Column) X 3 (Row)

Any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the offsetter transformer.

Adding a necessary X value will shift the floor to the side of the previous floor. You can use a conditional value for the X value, so when floor equals n make X value = (n x 10) for example. (this would lay out all plans in a single row)

To introduce rows with 5 floors per row include a conditional value on the Y axis and alter the x value:

for example:

if floor(n) in 0-5 then Y = 0 | X value = (n x 10)

if floor(n) in 6-10 then Y = -10 | X value = ((n -5) x 10)

if floor(n) in 11-15 then Y = -20 | X value = ((n -10) x 10)